# Question for review

Tags: writing, writing-style, peer-review

What are the type of question you can ask someone when you send you manuscript to for review. The person may not necessarily be in your field.

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. Are you the paper author or the reviewer in this situation?

Comment: @astronat I am the paper author. The reviewer is not necessarily one of a journal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost all review requests I receive do not contain specific questions, but rather something generic along the lines of: "*We have recently received a manuscript with the title '[...]'. Given your expertise in this area we feel you could offer timely and insightful comments on this work. We would be grateful for your willingness to help. If you accept, we would greatly appreciate a 30-day turn around.*" (For another e-mail template, see [this page under the header 'Referee Request'](https://blog.scholasticahq.com/post/peer-review-email-templates/).)

If you wish to formulate more specific questions, you could get inspiration from peer review guidelines. For instance, paraphrasing [this checklist from PLOS](https://plos.org/resource/peer-review-checklist/), one could ask:

- Identify the research question and key claims. Are they clear?
- Does the introduction provide a plausible context? Does it cite the relevant literature?
- Do the figures and tables represent what the study is about?
- Are the results supported by the data?
- Do the conclusions make sense?
- Are the methods appropriate and reproducible?

Or, [F1000](https://f1000research.com/for-referees/guidelines) offers these questions for research articles:

- Is the work clearly and accurately presented and does it cite the current literature?
- Is the study design appropriate and does the work have academic merit?
- Are sufficient details of methods and analysis provided to allow replication by others?
- If applicable, is the statistical analysis and its interpretation appropriate?
- Are all the source data underlying the results available to ensure full reproducibility?
- Are the conclusions drawn adequately supported by the results?

One could generate similar questions using [this guide from Wiley](https://authorservices.wiley.com/Reviewers/journal-reviewers/how-to-perform-a-peer-review/step-by-step-guide-to-reviewing-a-manuscript.html#10) (cf. the heading "How to Structure Your Report").

There are also multiple peer review templates around for teachers who use student peer reviews in their classes. Just google for "peer review templates for students" or so, and you will find plenty of them.